# Muliple table captions in DT in R

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, r-markdown, dt

I'm following the example from here: https://rstudio.github.io/DT/

I can get a caption above the table with:

```
library(DT)

datatable(
  head(iris),
  caption = 'Table 1: This is a simple caption for the table.'
)
```

And a caption below the table with:

```
library(DT)

datatable(
  head(iris),
  caption = htmltools::tags$caption(
    style = 'caption-side: bottom; text-align: center;',
    'Table 2: ', htmltools::em('This is a simple caption for the table.')
  )
)
```

How could I have two captions (above and below) at the same time?

Cheers,
Kate

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do as follows:

```
library(DT)

js <- c(
  "function(settings){",
  "  var datatable = settings.oInstance.api();",
  "  var table = datatable.table().node();",
  "  var caption = 'ANOTHER CAPTION'",
  "  $(table).append('<caption style=\"caption-side: bottom\">' + caption + '</caption>');",
  "}"
)

datatable(
  head(iris),
  options = list(
    drawCallback = JS(js)
  ),
  caption = 'Table 1: This is a simple caption for the table.'
)
```

[image]

Comment: very cool but soo complex..

Answer (score 1):

Good use of JS() to append a new caption after generation of the table. When I used this with tables that had pagination, the caption would append each time a different page of the data table was selected. To avoid the continuous appending, I would suggest using 'initComplete' instead of 'drawCallback' as the option. Drawing from Stephane Laurent's code:

```
library(DT)

js <- c(
  "function(settings){",
  "  var datatable = settings.oInstance.api();",
  "  var table = datatable.table().node();",
  "  var caption = 'ANOTHER CAPTION'",
  "  $(table).append('<caption style=\"caption-side: bottom\">' + caption + '</caption>');",
  "}"
)

datatable(
  head(iris),
  options = list(
    initComplete = JS(js) #This will avoid looping of the caption when there is pagination
  ),
  caption = 'Table 1: This is a simple caption for the table.'
)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31492399)

Comment: This was my attempt to offer a comment to Stéphane Laurent's answer, but do not yet have sufficient reputation to comment on the post.

Comment: Understood! If you wanted to update your post with code using `initComplete` instead of `drawCallback` that answers the question, I'm happy to update my review ✌

Comment: Very nice. Two questions: 1. How to align one/both captions to e.g. the left? 2. How to change e.g. only the bottom caption font color and/or bold it?